# Using a delimiter in scanner; ignoring spaces & new lines

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Good day,

I am trying to read a txt file using scanner, and save the characters into a 2D String array. The txt file consists of 8 lines of characters, not separated by spaces. My program works (if you remove the delimiter) if they are separated by spaces, or (including the delimiter) without spaces if the characters are all in one line.

If someone could show me how to save the characters correctly that would be greatly appreciated. The problem is in the Read() function, with the double for-loop. I tried adding another delimiter (s.useDelimiter(s.nextLine())) but I do not know how to implement it.

Keep in mind this is my first time using a scanner for a file and I'm only learning programming, thus my code won't be very advanced.

Kind regards,
Matthew

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class BoardFile {

    String[][] board = new String[8][8];
    Scanner s;

    // Print the board
    public void Printboard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void Open() {
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("**TXT FILE PATHNAME HERE**"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public void Read() {
        s.useDelimiter("");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                String a = s.next();
                board[i][j] = a;
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoardFile a = new BoardFile();
        a.Open();
        a.Read();
        a.Printboard();
    }
}
```

The txt file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8fkneg2dcw0cbe/abcde.txt?dl=0

Comment: If your board array should really be 8 characters by 8 lines, it probably should be of type `char[][]`, rather than `String[][]`. As for the reading - I think it would be better to read a whole line, without changing the delimiter, and then break that line into characters using `toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scanner's nextline() and split() function to read your result into 2d array

```
public void Read() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                board[i]= s.nextLine().split("");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2 dimensional array, you should use char[][] and not String[][] 
Here is the program which works.

```
package com.jvit.vm;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoardFile {

    char[][] board = new char[8][8];
    Scanner s;

    // Print the board
    public void Printboard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void Open() {
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public void Read() {
        s.useDelimiter("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            char[] chars = s.next().toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                board[i][j] = chars[j];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoardFile a = new BoardFile();
        a.Open();
        a.Read();
        a.Printboard();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Read() {
    String[] delimeter = { " ", "\\.", ",", "\\z"}
    for (String delimeter : delimeter)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(args[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                String a = s.next();
                board[i][j] = a;
            }
        }   
        scanner.useDelimiter(delimeter);
        String t = scanner.next();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scanners skip method (as per the below) the pattern "\n*" means one or more newline characters in the input

```
public void Read() {
    s.useDelimiter("");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            s.skip("\n*");
            String a = s.next();
            board[i][j] = a;
        }
    }   
}
```